# ActionCable subscriber does not get an update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

Consider **scenario** in the App:

- User submits an answer then gets taken to a page where they get subscribed to an ActionCable.
- Every time a user submits an answer, a broadcast also happens so that subscribed users can be updated with the new user and their answer.

**Problem**: When two users submits an answer at almost the same time (within 1 second)

- one user ends up seeing two answers, theirs and the other user
- the other user ends up only seeing their answer

**Question**:

- Is there a way to make it so that both players see each other's answers?

I've been searching for solutions but have not found any. I may have stumbled upon the cause of the issue from [rubyonrails.org](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Streams.html):

> If you're not streaming a broadcasting at the very moment it sends out an update, you will not get that update, even if you connect after it has been sent.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make it so that both players see each other's answers?

Load the answers from the database on page load, and only use broadcasts to "update" what gets seen on-screen in real-time.

If updates are broadcasted for data already on-screen, either do nothing or use that to replace the answer already shown.

Subscribing to or listening to WebSocket messages is like tuning into a radio station. You have no idea what may have broadcasted before you started listening, so you'll need to get that data from elsewhere.

Alternatively, if you'd prefer to start with a blank slate, you could instruct the client-side code that after it is subscribed, to make an API call (or ActionCable request) to get all the relevant data needed, and also use broadcasts to "update" that data.